# Enabling Zendesk push notification identifier

Tags: android, zendesk

I am having this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 114228806971 at line 1 column 47 path $.push_notification_device.id
```

whenever I am doing

```
 ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.enablePushWithIdentifier
```

can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried searching and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an older version. This was fixed in version 1.10.1.1, although [1.11.0.1 is available now](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/version_information#release-notes)

Thanks!